# Ionic 2 - iOS NotRegistered

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, ionic2, phonegap-build

I have done an App in Ionic 2 with the phonegap-plugin-push for notifications.

It works really well with Android but when I try to run it on the iOS it have a few problems.

I can get the registration token but when I do a push message I get the error: NotRegistered as response.

What can it be? The wrong certeficates or some bug in code?

I'm using Ionic 2 on a windows, using phonegap to compile the app to iOS so I have to generate the certificates with openSSL.

There is a few of the code for the push notifications:

> config.xml

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.8.2">
   <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="883847118563"/>
</plugin>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import {Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from "@ionic-native/push";
(...)
platform.ready().then(() => {
  (...)
  this.initPushNotification();
});

initPushNotification() { 
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  (...)
}
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
    senderID: "8838XXXXXXXX"
  },
  ios: {
    senderID: "8838XXXXXXXX" ,
    gcmSandbox: "true",
    alert: "true",
    badge: false,
    sound: 'true'
  },
  windows: {}
};
const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
  (...)
});

pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
  (...)
});

pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
 'core': {
  'app_id': 'bdeXXXX'
  },
'push': {
  'sender_id': '8838XXXXXXXX',
  'pluginConfig': {
    'ios': {
      'badge': true,
      'sound': true
     },
    'android': {
     'iconColor': '#ff0000'
    }
  }
 }
};
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @noor Well, I stop using phonegap and used Xcode in a mac, I just open the project there and compiled and everything work well, also, it's easier to set up the right certificates on firebase